# Set CD Title - burning a CD with VB Script using IMAPI2

Tags: vbscript

I'm creating a CD with VB Script using IMAPI2. It works fine, but how can I set a cd-title?

This is exactly the script I'm using:

--> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364817(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/eb034c50-7ada-485b-9669-cb5665ed5095/creating-iso-files-with-vbscript-possible?forum=windowsopticalplatform):

```
FSI.VolumeName = "Stackoverflow"
```

Maybe using `volume label` or `volume name` as search keywords could help you to get better results.

Comment: Thank you, thats exactly what I was looking for! I will search better next time ;-)